# How to find file path in magento - Sales, Processing Order, Create New Order, Add Product, Add Selected Products to Order

Tags: magento-1.7

I am new to Magento. Please can anyone tell me the path of file in Magento's admin panel - Sales, Processing Order, Create New Order, Add Product, Add Selected Products to Order - In that Update Items and Qty's button.

Where the code is written for updating products in admin panel?

Comment: enable the template path hints in admin and u will be able to figure it out yourself

Comment: How to enable templat path hints in admin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install extension [Easy Template Path Hints](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-template-path-hints.html)

Just add query string: ?tp=1&code=code-configured-in-backend to any url of backend or frontend.

For example: 
Frontend: `http://magento-url/apparel/shirts/zolof-the-rock-and-roll-destroyer-lol-cat-t-shirt.html?tp=1&code=magento`

Backend: `http://magento-url/admin/admin/catalog_product/index/key/be8877b200d0bf2a8a32dc21e42eb0e5/?tp=1&code=magento`

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to install any module for this. 
You can enable the path hints directly from database by using below query :

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`)
       VALUES ('websites', '0', 'dev/debug/template_hints', '1');
```

When you wwant to turn off the hints, just update the `value` field to `0`

Comment: very nice answer

Comment: I got the below error when changing the value to '0':Duplicate entry 'websites-0-dev/debug/template_hints' for key 'UNQ_CORE_CONFIG_DATA_SCOPE_SCOPE_ID_PATH'